# Create a File Dialog

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery

I have a webpage that I want to allow the user to save the contents to his machine.  The webpage is already using AJAX with prototype.js.  The server side code is written in PHP.  How can I create a File Dialog so the user can specify the file to save the data too?  The server is running Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

PHP:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
header('Content-disposition:attachment; filename="yourfile.txt"');
```